# Installation - select option with shell script

Tags: linux

I'm installing `php-pear` and during the installation I have to select options for region, timezone, etc.

Can I select options using the `sh` script?

Example: 1=Asia 2=America, etc.

In my `sh` script, it will automatically select option 2 which I will set in `.sh`.

The command that I'm using:

```
apt install php-pear -y
```

[image]

Comment: Cross site answer from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7245893/2422776

Comment: It worked... But I had to remove the `spawn`.

Thank you very much @Mureinik